# JavaScript: jQuery Datepicker - simple highlighting of specific days, who can help? (source inside)

Tags: jquery, datepicker, highlight

i want to use the Datepicker for highlighting specific dates. Here is my latest code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var dates = [30/04/2010, 01/05/2010];

$(function(){

    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: [2,3],                
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        beforeShowDay: highlightDays
    });

    function highlightDays(date) {
        for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
            if (dates[i] == date) {
                          return [true, 'highlight'];
                  }
          }
          return [true, ''];

 }   

});
 </script>
```

my CSS is:

```
#highlight, .highlight {
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

Well the calendar comes up, but there is nothing highlighted. Where is the problem in my code?
If anyone could help that would be great.

Another option/solution could be: disable all dates, but make available only dates in an array.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

let tell you some of the problems...

1 . var dates = [30/04/2010, 01/05/2010];

would not store your dates as expected... it will do math operations...

2.  change it to string but in this format: `mm/dd/yy` 
 so, you should have something like:

```
var dates = ['04/30/2010', '05/01/2010'];
```

3.  use this function:

```
function highlightDays(date) {
        for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
            if (new Date(dates[i]).toString() == date.toString()) {              
                          return [true, 'highlight'];
                  }
          }
          return [true, ''];

 }
```

4.  CSS as:

```
td.highlight {
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px blue solid;
}
```

5.  [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/o0o7u4k3/)

Comment: how the parameter "date" is initialized what is the start and end date of that value for function highlightDays(date) ?

Answer (score 3):

There is problem with timezone.

```
function highlightDays(date) {
    for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
        if (new Date(dates[i]).toString().substr(0, 16) == date.toString().substr(0, 16)) {
            return [true, 'highlight'];
        }
    }
    return [true, ''];
 }
```