# How to highlight the day in datepicker on click of text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Here is my code

```
 <input type="text" name="date" class="datepicker" value="20-Jun-2017" readonly="">



$(".datepicker").each(function() { 

    var date_val = $(this).val();

    $(this).datepicker({

        'setDate':  date_val,

        'pickDate': true,

        'dateFormat': 'd-M-y'
    });
});
```

datepicker is highlighting only today's date, but not default textbox value.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what plugin you are using for datepicker.. Can you provide link to the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DatePicker highlights the selected date automatically, but there is a problem with your format of year. If you set it as 17 rather 2017, it will work.

Else try setting the date after initialization like below.

```
$(".datepicker").each(function() { 

var date_val = $(this).val();

$(this).datepicker({ 

    'pickDate': true,

    'dateFormat': 'd-M-y'
});

$(this).datepicker( "setDate", new Date(date_val) );
});
```

Comment: Thanks Prashant :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" value="1-Jun-17" />

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    'dateFormat': 'd-M-y'
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cubttgow/41/)

Answer (score 0):

Hi date picker will automatically highlights selected dates, but you can highlight dates manually as well, please refer below link

[Datepicker for highlighting specific dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735207/javascript-jquery-datepicker-simple-highlighting-of-specific-days-who-can-he)