# adding a class to a calendar day in jQuery UI (MultipleDates)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm using Multiple Dates picker for jQuery UI date picker. Everything was going fine until now. Turns out the developer who made it hasn't touched it in years and pre-highlighting dates no longer works. So here's my plan. I'll place my dates that i need highlighted into an array, then using jQuery to add the necessary class to the calendars. That's where I'm stuck. How do I target this particular anchor when the it looks like this:

```
<td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end  ui-datepicker-current-day" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="10" data-year="2017">
<a class="ui-state-default" href="#">18</a> <!-- needs class: ui-state-active-->
</td>
```

So how do I target based on data-month, data-year and then the number that's in the anchor? All help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger the function with beforeShowDay event.

**UPDATED**: [JavaScript: jQuery Datepicker - simple highlighting of specific days, who can help? (source inside)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735207/javascript-jquery-datepicker-simple-highlighting-of-specific-days-who-can-he)

Comment: i'll give that  a shot. ideally i would like to use the same classes that the plugin uses, that way i'm simulating that it's been clicked, at least programatically

Comment: It is not about the classes. It is native callback for this jQuery plugin and you don't need to have any kind of selector because that would be third party with all the consequences: complex dependencies and forbidden updates. Everything is simple like: Can you build selector? Yes. Do you need one? No, it is bad coding practice.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value inside the anchor tag you can use jQuery selectors to narrow down the search using the month and year.

Then loop through all the days in that month and year and use the find() method on the anchor to get the day. compare the calendar date to the date in your array and if they match, highlight it

Here is an example, but I am not sure about the performance or how it will scale.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var myDates = ["10/18/2017", "10/20/2017"];
  myDates.forEach(function(dateString) {
    var date = new Date(dateString);
    var currMonth = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var currYear = date.getFullYear();
    var currDay = date.getDate();

    var $monthYear = $(`td[data-month='${currMonth}'][data-year='${currYear}']`);
    $monthYear.each(function(i, elem) {
      var calendarDay = $(elem).find("a").text();
      var currDate = `${currMonth}/${calendarDay}/${currYear}`;
      if (dateString === currDate) {
        $(elem).addClass("highlight");
      }
    });
  })
})
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end  ui-datepicker-current-day" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="10" data-year="2017">
      <a class="ui-state-default" href="#">18</a>
      <!-- needs class: ui-state-active-->
    </td>

    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end  ui-datepicker-current-day" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="10" data-year="2017">
      <a class="ui-state-default" href="#">19</a>
      <!-- needs class: ui-state-active-->
    </td>

    <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end  ui-datepicker-current-day" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="10" data-year="2017">
      <a class="ui-state-default" href="#">20</a>
      <!-- needs class: ui-state-active-->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: hmm... looks like that would go through all days in the month. How would you target a specific day and then add a class to it? if(day=='18'){day.addClass('ui-state-active')}?

Comment: I updated my answer to be more generic, it includes an array like you specified and adding the class to the date